# fullcalendar js: fetching more events with ajax

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar),
how can I fetch more events from same server side, multiple urls?
The initial one works, I just want to add additional events when they arrive(ajax).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Ajax to get the data and then add dynamically the new source

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(data){
       var source = { events: [
                            {
                                title: data.getTitle(),
                                start: new Date(year, month, day)
                            }
                ]};
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If each and every time you are using a different URL, then you can simply use [addEventSource](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) with the new URL.

If you are attempting to use the same URL, you can get all events (old and new) using [refetchEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/).

You can also get the JSON and create the event as a client event using [renderEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/).  The latter is the most "ajax-y" of the options.  In this case have your source return the JSON that represents the events, iterate through the array of new events, and call renderEvent on it.

```
// this call goes in a poll or happens when the something should trigger a
// fetching of new events
$.ajax({
  url: "path/to/event/source",
  success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(index, event)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call done can also insert in the calendar code

```
      $.ajax({ 
            url: url, 
            type: 'GET', 
            data: { }, 
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            } 
        }).done(function (doc) { 
                var event = Array();
                    $.each(doc, function(i, entry) 
                        event.push({title: entry.title, start: entry.start});
                    }); 
                 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
                    editable: true,
                    events: event
                });

     });
```