# Need to return to Full Calendar after JSON-events called from POST method

Tags: php, json, forms, post, fullcalendar

I am using JQuery Full Calendar to display the results of a JSON feed from my mysql localhost. Initially it updates from the Calendar function using `events: "json-events.php",`, but I am also trying to run `json-events.php` from a submit button on a form using POST method and a submit button. While the JSON feed works great, I only get an ECHO of the results, and cannot get back to index.php to display the results on the calendar.
Code for json-events.php...

```
<?php

$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$day = date('d');

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db('jauntUK');

$latevent = $row['Lat'];
$lngevent = $row['Long'];
$tgtlat = $_POST['searchlat'];
$tgtlatstring = number_format($tgtlat, 16, '.', '');
$tgtlng = $_POST['searchlong'];
$tgtlngstring = number_format($tgtlng, 16, '.', '');


if($_POST) {


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians(" . $tgtlatstring . ") ) * cos( radians(" . $tgtlngstring . ") - radians( `Long` ) ) + sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) * sin( radians(" . $tgtlatstring . ") ) ) ) AS distance FROM EventData HAVING distance < 5")
or die (mysql_error());

// Initializes a container array for all of the calendar events
$jsonArray = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    var_dump($row);

 $eventtitle = $row['Title'];
 $eventdate = $row['StartDate'];
 $eventend = $row['EndDate'];
 $eventallday = $row['FullDay'];
 $eventURL = $row['URL'];
 $Description = $row['Description'];
 $Address1 = $row['Address1'];
 $Address2 = $row['Address2'];
 $Address3 = $row['Address3'];
 $Address4 = $row['Address4'];
 $PostCode = $row['PostCode'];
 $Admission = $row['Admission'];

 // Stores each database record to an array
 $buildjson = array('title' => "$eventtitle", 'start' => "$eventdate", 'end' => "$eventend", 'allday' => "$eventallday", 'eventURL' => "$URL", 'description' => "$Description", 'Address1' => "$Address1", 'Address2' => "$Address2", 'Address3' => "$Address3", 'Address4' => "$Address4", 'PostCode' => "$PostCode", 'Admission' => "$Admission");

 // Adds each array into the container array
 array_push($jsonArray, $buildjson);
}
// Output the json formatted data so that the jQuery call can read it
echo json_encode($jsonArray);   
header('location: index.php');


 } else { 


 echo json_encode(array(

        array(
            'id' => 001,
            'title' => "Search for events near you",
            'start' => "$year-$month-$day",

        )

    ));
}
?>
```

Any advice? - thanks in advance for your help

Comment: P.S. - I have tried `header('Location:index.php');`, but all I get is `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you are wanting to keep the old events and just add the new ones? Or only show the new events? If it's the former, you might try using AJAX instead of submitting the form and redirecting back to the index.php. You can return the data on success and use http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/  to render it. Something like this

```
('#submit-button').on("click",function(){

  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "json-events.php",
        data: $('#your-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
                        $.each(data, function(index, event){
                          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
                        );
        }
    });
    return false;  // to stop the form from actually submitting
});
```

You will need to add this code anywhere inside your document ready function on the page with your calendar. When the submit button is clicked on your form it will send the data from your form to your json-events.php page. There you query your database and return the events with json_encode. In the success function you then render each event that you just pulled from the database. I borrowed the example above from [fullcalendar js: fetching more events with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218224/fullcalendar-js-fetching-more-events-with-ajax) No idea if it works but you can see the idea.

If you don't want to show the old events you may look at adding

```
('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
```

before you add the new ones.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking time to reply, and sorry its taken me so long to get back to you. It is the latter I am looking to do, and I'm fairly new to coding, so could do with understanding where this code fits, and how to call it. Thanks

Comment: @Mark, I updated my answer to give a little more info. Hopefully it helps explain it a little more