# How to populate the full calendar events from the separate json file using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have the code which produces the full calendar with the events. The event items are given specified by the inline format. I want to achieve the same thing by giving event details in separate json.

Question 2 : When i click the particular event it shows a popover. but I need the popover when i mouse hover to the particular event.

Question 3 : how to specify the date with this format 2014-08-06 or else with some timestamp.

I followed the below code link..
fiddle

Comment: fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/7gwz5/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [fullcalendar js: fetching more events with ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218224/fullcalendar-js-fetching-more-events-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

The ajax call done can also insert in the calendar code

```
  $.ajax({ 
        url: url, 
        type: 'GET', 
        data: { }, 
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        } 
    }).done(function (doc) { 
            var event = Array();
                $.each(doc, function(i, entry) 
                    event.push({title: entry.title, start: entry.start});
                }); 
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
                editable: true,
                events: event
            });

 });
```

Comment: Don't copy and paste the same answer to two questions. Instead, flag one of them as a duplicate of the other.